# sql join within join?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I need your help building a SQL statement I can't wrap my head around.

In a database, I have four tables - files, folders, folders_files and links.

I have many files. One of them is called "myFile.txt".

I have many folders. "myFile.txt" is in some of them. The first folder it appears in is called "firstFolder".

I have many links to many folders. The first link to "firstFolder" is called "firstLink".

The data structure for the example would be:

```
// files
Id: 10
Name: "myFile.txt"

// folders
Id: 20
Name: "firstFolder"

// folder_files (join table)
Id: 30
Folder_Id: 20 (meaning "firstFolder")
File_Id: 1 (meaning "myFile.txt")

// links
Id: 40
Name: "firstLink"
Folder_Id: 20 (meaning "firstFolder")
```

FIRST QUESTION: How do I get the record for "myFile.txt" AND the Name and Id of "firstLink" (the first link), querying on file Id = 10, based on the lowest Id of the folder and the link?

SECOND QUESTION: How do I get the record for "myFile.txt" AND the Name and Id of "firstLink" (the first link), querying on all files, based on the lowest Id of the folder and the link?

put another way - how do I get the first link to the first folder containing "myFile.txt"?

Resulting in a record that looks like:

```
Id: 10
Name: "myFile.txt"
LinkId: 40
LinkName: "firstLink"
```

Thanks!

Comment: By 'first', do you mean with the lowest ID?

Comment: I added tag `greatest-n-per-group`.  Try clicking on that tag and you'll see many other cases of the equivalent problem, with solutions.  Try reading some of those and then come back and edit your question with what you tried (it's always better to do your homework yourself).  Sorry I had to cannibalize your `subselect` tag because there's a limit of five tags.  But you don't necessarily need a subselect to solve this problem.

Comment: @Wrikken - yes, lowest Id.

@bill - thanks for the edit, tho I'm newbie enough at SQL, that I don't really see how greatest-n-per-group relates? I think I'm just doing joins...? I dug around this forum and the web for an hour before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to think about how you want your result set to look.  SQL is designed to describe result sets.  If you can write out a hypothetical result set, you might have an easier time writing SQL that will render that result set.

I had a hard time understanding what you are looking for, but I'm sure it's a fairly straight forward problem.  I would be able to help you easier if you could describe you results more clearly, although you might not need my help anymore!

For example (going with you original schema) Q1 & Q2:

`files.Id, files.Name, links.Id, links.Name` (4 columns)

Q1:

```
SELECT
  files.Id, files.Name, links.Id, links.Name
FROM
  files, links
INNER JOIN
  folder_files
  ON files.Id = folder_files.File_Id
INNER JOIN
  links
  ON links.Id = folder_files.Folder_Id
WHERE
  files.Id = 10
ORDER BY
  folder_files.File_Id ASC, links.Id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

*(`JOIN` with folders table not necessary)*

Q2:

Change both `ASC` to `DESC`

Comment: Thanks - I thought of that shortly after publishing, but it didn't show up in my edit. It's there now.

Comment: That's it! Two inner joins! That's what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This selects all links for file id 10:

```
select links.id, links.name
 from files
 left join folder_files on files.id = folder_files.file_id
 left join folders on folder_files.folder_id = folders.id
 left join links on links.folder_id = folders.id
 where files.id=10;
```

Change the where clause, add limit or whatever for other things you want. It should be simple to modify this.

Comment: Sorry I phrased my question wrong. I want to get the Name and Id of the link, along with the record data for the file. So they aren't separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
select f.*
        , l.Id as LinkId
        , l.Name as LinkName, 
    from Link l
        inner join Folder_Files ff on ff.Folder_Id = l.Folder_Id
        inner join Files f on f.Id = ff.File_Id
    where f.Id = 10
```

Resulting to:

```
 Id | Name       | LinkId | LinkName
 10 | myFile.txt | 40     | firstLink
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account:

- more folders per file
- more links per folder
- taking the lowest id folder for link, and lowest id link for folder

With help of: [mysql: group by ID, get highest priority per each ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097321/mysql-group-by-id-get-highest-priority-per-each-id/3097336#3097336)

The answer for ALL files in the files table ( go for JohnB's solution for a single file, it would be faster):

```
SELECT file_id, file_name, link_id, link_name FROM (
SELECT file_id, file_name, link_id, link_name,
    @r := CASE WHEN @prev_file_id = file_id
                    THEN @rn + 1
                    ELSE 1
               END AS r,
    @prev_file_id := file_id
FROM (
    SELECT
        f.id as file_id, f.name as file_name, l.id as link_id, l.name as link_name
    FROM files f
    JOIN folder_files ff
    ON ff.file_id = f.id
    JOIN links l
    ON l.folder_id = ff.folder_id
    ORDER BY ff.folder_id, l.id -- first folder first, first link to first folder second
) derived1,
(SELECT @prev_file_id := NULL,@r:=0) vars
) derived2
WHERE r = 1;
```