# Problem with MySQL query for high scores leaderboard

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a MySQL high scores table for a game that shows the daily high score for each of the past days of the year. Right now I am doing a PHP for-loop and making a separate query for each day, but the table is becoming too large to do that so I would like to condense it into one simple MySQL statement.

Here is my new query right now (date_submitted is a timestamp):

```
SELECT date(date_submitted) as subDate, name, score FROM highScores WHERE date_submitted > "2009-07-16" GROUP BY subDate ORDER BY subDate DESC, score DESC LIMIT 10;
```

output:

```
+------------+------------+--------+
| subDate    | name       | score  |
+------------+------------+--------+
| 2010-07-18 | krissy     | 959976 |
| 2010-07-10 | claire     | 260261 |
| 2010-07-05 | krissy     | 771416 |
| 2010-06-19 | krissy     | 698031 |
| 2010-06-18 | otli       | 264898 |
| 2010-06-15 | robbie     |  82303 |
| 2010-06-01 | dad        | 480469 |
| 2010-05-29 | vicente    | 124149 |
| 2010-05-27 | dad        | 564007 |
| 2010-05-26 | caleb      | 502623 |
+------------+------------+--------+
```

My problem is that when it grouped by subDate, it took the highest score for the earliest timestamp of that day, as you can see in the next query:

```
SELECT name, score, date_submitted FROM highScores WHERE date(date_submitted)='2010-06-15' GROUP BY name ORDER BY score DESC;
```

output:

```
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| name   | score  | date_submitted      |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| john   | 304095 | 2010-06-15 22:58:02 |
| april  | 247126 | 2010-06-15 21:25:31 |
| orli   | 166021 | 2010-06-15 21:25:31 |
| robbie |  82303 | 2010-06-15 11:38:39 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, poor john should have been the leader for 2010-06-15. Can anyone help? Hopefully it is something real simple I am overlooking. I tried using max(score) before the FROM part in the 1st query and it gave me the correct score but didn't carry over the name.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT userName, userScore, subDate FROM (
    SELECT 
        userName,
        userScrore,
        DATE(submitDate) as subDate,
        @rn := CASE WHEN @subDate = DATE(submitDate)
                THEN @rn + 1
                ELSE 1
           END AS rn,
        @subDate := DATE(submitDate)
    FROM (SELECT @subDate := NULL) vars, highScores
    ORDER BY submitDate, userScore DESC
) deriv
WHERE rn=1;
```

See also the answer to another ['highest record per something'-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097321/mysql-group-by-id-get-highest-priority-per-each-id/3097605#3097605https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097321/mysql-group-by-id-get-highest-priority-per-each-id)

Comment: Hey thank you. This is beyond my MySQL experience but I think I'm beginning to understand it.

However, when I run this from the MySQL command line:

SELECT name, score, subDate FROM (
    SELECT 
        name,
        score,
        DATE(date_submitted) AS subDate,
        @rn ..... etc...

I get this error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 
        name,
        score,
        DATE(date_submitted) AS' at line 2

Comment: Hey thanks. I just tried it again and rewrote it instead of copy-paste and it worked! The error I was getting was some extra whitespace line carriage or something from copying it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
ORDER BY userScore DESC
```

at the end of the second query.

Comment: I put "ORDER BY score DESC" at the end of the second query. So that query is sorting correctly.

Comment: I just tried changing "score DESC" to "score ASC" in the first query just to see if it acknowledged the 2nd part of the ORDER BY and it gave me the exact same output in the first query so that's weird.

Comment: it looks like it corrected the second output, unless i am mistaken.

Comment: Yeah it sorts the 2nd output now. It shows john as the highest score for that day but still in the first query it doesn't matter if I do score ASC or score DESC. I think maybe I might have to do something complicated like the 2nd answer.